# Trying to use Python to properly indent and dedent asp code

Tags: python

I am trying to use Python to properly indent and dedent asp code.
Similar to http://www.aspindent.com/ I am trying to properly indent and dedent some asp code I am working with. The problem is, is that the asp code is too long to be parsed by the website.

That is when I decided I should just try and program it myself. 
In going this approach I've run into a few problems I need help solving.

Here is a segment of example code that may be parsed by my program

```
if some_bool then
code
code
code
end if
code
code
```

It will then properly indent the code and then it turns into this

```
if some_bool then
    code
    code
    code
    end if
code
code
```

As you can see the last `end if` is also indented
I'm not sure how to properly go about dedenting the end if statement at the end. I'm trying to maintain a DRY approach in my code, and I recognized immediately that trying to fix this part could get really weird. So some hints would be appreciated for this part.

Lastly, Please let me know if there are any other indenting and dedenting keywords I should pay attention too.

Here is the code I've created so far.

```
"""
IF BOOL THEN
    CODE
    CODE
END IF

IF BOOL THEN
    CODE
    CODE
ELSEIF BOOL THEN
    CODE
    CODE
END IF

IF BOOL THEN
    CODE
    IF BOOL THEN
        CODE
    END IF
    CODE

    IF BOOL THEN
        CODE
    ELSEIF BOOL THEN
        CODE
    END IF
    CODE
END IF


"""

import re, sys


def print_ln(space, string):
    sys.stdout.write(" " * space + str(string))
    sys.stdout.flush()


def main(string):
    space = 0
    for s in string:
        print_ln(space, s)
        if re.search("^\s*if.*then", str(s), re.IGNORECASE):
            space += 4
        if re.search("^\s*for", str(s), re.IGNORECASE):
            space += 4
        if re.search("^\s*elseif.*then", str(s), re.IGNORECASE):
            space -= 4
        if re.search("^\s*end if", str(s), re.IGNORECASE):
            space -= 4
        if re.search("^\s*next", str(s), re.IGNORECASE):
            space -= 4


with open("scratch.html") as s:
    main(s.readlines())
```

Comment: Ouch. That line that reads `END IF\nCODE` more literally `[\ ]{4}END IF\n[\ ]{4}CODE` will mess almost everything up. I was going at it by splitting this into stanzas based on findall with `(?i)(IF[\S\s]*?END[\ ]*?IF(?=\n{2,}|$))` then doing the indentation there, but the line mentioned posed a problem for me. Sorry mate.

Answer (score 0):

Indenting is easy, dedenting is easy. Dedenting and then indenting requires a little forethought about the way the text is being printed, but also easy.

To make this work we need to split up the task aforementioned into their own functions. This includes having the line prints tacked to these functions as well. This will control when to print and not to print.

Code below.

```
"""
IF BOOL THEN
    CODE
    CODE
END IF

IF BOOL THEN
    CODE
    CODE
ELSEIF BOOL THEN
    CODE
    CODE
END IF

IF BOOL THEN
    CODE
    IF BOOL THEN
        CODE
    END IF
    CODE

    IF BOOL THEN
        CODE
    ELSEIF BOOL THEN
        CODE
    END IF
    CODE
END IF


"""

import re, sys


class Indenter:
    def __init__(self, string):
        self.space = 0
        self.count = 0
        self.string = string

    def print_ln(self, string):
        sys.stdout.write(" " * self.space + str(string))
        sys.stdout.flush()

    def indent(self):
        self.print_ln(self.string[self.count])
        self.space += 4

    def dedent(self):
        self.space -= 4
        self.print_ln(self.string[self.count])

    def dedent_indent(self):
        self.space -= 4
        self.print_ln(self.string[self.count])
        self.space += 4

    def main(self):
        while self.count < len(self.string):
            if re.search("^\s*if.*then", str(self.string[self.count]), re.IGNORECASE):
                self.indent()
            elif re.search("^\s*for", str(self.string[self.count]), re.IGNORECASE):
                self.indent()
            elif re.search("^\s*with", str(self.string[self.count]), re.IGNORECASE):
                self.indent()
            elif re.search("^\s*do until", str(self.string[self.count]), re.IGNORECASE):
                self.indent()
            elif re.search("^\s*do", str(self.string[self.count]), re.IGNORECASE):
                self.indent()
            elif re.search("^\s*Select Case", str(self.string[self.count]), re.IGNORECASE):
                self.indent()

            elif re.search("^\s*End Select", str(self.string[self.count]), re.IGNORECASE):
                self.dedent()
            elif re.search("^\s*loop", str(self.string[self.count]), re.IGNORECASE):
                self.dedent()
            elif re.search("^\s*end with", str(self.string[self.count]), re.IGNORECASE):
                self.dedent()
            elif re.search("^\s*end if", str(self.string[self.count]), re.IGNORECASE):
                self.dedent()
            elif re.search("^\s*next", str(self.string[self.count]), re.IGNORECASE):
                self.dedent()

            elif re.search("^\s*Case", str(self.string[self.count]), re.IGNORECASE):
                self.dedent_indent()
            elif re.search("^\s*else", str(self.string[self.count]), re.IGNORECASE):
                self.dedent_indent()
            elif re.search("^\s*elseif.*then", str(self.string[self.count]), re.IGNORECASE):
                self.dedent_indent()

            else:
                self.print_ln(self.string[self.count])
            self.count += 1


with open("scratch.html") as s:
    ind = Indenter(s.readlines())
    ind.main()
```